# Arch linux -- polkit auth_admin_keep setting doesn't remember authorization?

Tags: arch-linux, polkit

Today, after I entered the password for the service shutdown/start process with systemctl, I wanted to set it to not ask for permission for 5-10 minutes. That's why when I entered the policy settings, I saw that it was already set to auth_admin_keep.

```
        <action id="org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units">
                <description gettext-domain="systemd">Manage system services or other units</description>
                <message gettext-domain="systemd">Authentication is required to manage system services or other units.</message>
                <defaults>
                        <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
                        <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
                        <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
                </defaults>
        </action>
```

To make sure Polkit is working properly, I went into pkexec's policy settings and made the new settings as follows

```
    <defaults>
      <allow_any>auth_admin</allow_any>
      <allow_inactive>auth_admin</allow_inactive>
      <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
    </defaults>
```

and strangely pkexec remembered my permission after I entered my password, but systemctl doesn't remember it.

Why could this be and how can I make systemctl remember my permission?

Answer (score 0):

Same behavior on Debian 11 / Gnome 3.38. The `keep` part of `auth_admin_keep` isn't always working.

I think it's the same with all the `org.gnome` actions (I tested `org.gnome.controlcenter.datetime.policy` and `org.gnome.controlcenter.user-ccounts.policy`).

Note : Suse has `auth_admin_keep_session` and `auth_admin_keep_always`, but they don't work in Debian (https://documentation.suse.com/sles/15-SP2/html/SLES-all/cha-security-policykit.html)

I suggest you remove `Arch Linux` from your post title, because it concerns Debian too, and probably some other distros (Ubuntu ?)